# How to compute Blum Blum Shub algorithm

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

So I have the m = p x q, p = 7 and q = 11

m = 77

S (which is the seed) = 4

Xi = 4^2 mod 77

from here I didn't know to continue the algorithm. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE! **What research have you done?** I'm asking because sharing research efforts helps everyone! Tell us what research you did, what you found, and why it didn’t meet your needs. That shows us you took time trying to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and (most important) it helps you to get more relevant answers. In case of doubt, start by reading [**the B.B.S. paper**](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0215025). At worst it will help you frame [*“a better question”*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); at best it might even answer it.